# Create a function that scans for available blue tooth devices(Javascript)

Tags: javascript, html, bluetooth

I am looking to create and then call on a function that can scan available bluetooth devices. right now I am just looking to create a function that will list all the devices. Nothing more. Is there any way to do this without referencing an html link or script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't search for bluetooth devices using only javascript. You can, however, set a service that scans the devices and you read that with an api call using javascript.

please refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24900797/showing-bluetooth-devices-in-range-via-browser)

Comment: I am attempting to do this using google dev tools, watched a few tutorials and read some posts. can you offer any helpful advice or tips for a beginner?